# How to @Html.DisplayNameFor() on a property of a list’s base class property?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

```
public class BaseModel 
{
    public Guid ID;
    public string Name;
    public List<BaseModelChildModel> BaseModelChildModels;
}

public class BaseModelChildModel
{
    public double Value;
    public string Notes;
    public BaseModel BaseModel;
    public ChildModel ChildModel;
}

public class ChildModel
{
    public Guid ID;
    public string Name;
    public int Productivity;
    public bool IsActive;
 }
```

In cshtml, where

```
@model BaseModel
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor()</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

How to make `@Html.DisplayNameFor()` display the proper name for `ChildModel.Name` or `ChildModel.IsActive` given that `BaseModel.BaseModelChildModels` contains 0 elements about half the time? (the proper display names acquired through `local.resx`, if it makes a difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the property to `IEnumerable<BaseModelChildModel>`, then you should be able to do:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.BaseModelChildModels.Foo)
```

Otherwise, you can index the property. The expression here is not every actually accessed, it's only evaluated to get at the display name. As a result, indexing the property will not cause an error if there's no items in the list as it traditionally would:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.BaseModelChildModels[0].Foo)
```

Comment: So, in other words, bring `Name` from `ChildModel` into `BaseModelChildModel`? The way this whole thing needs to work is that access to properties from BaseModel, BaseModelChildModel, and from ChildModel needs to be available in the UI at the same time and then, in another view, they are actually inverted, so that BaseModelChildModel is actually a pivot in a relational database which contains additional data. Based on your response, the best way I see is to produce a new model for the view, which means more load on the T4 templates.

Comment: No. You don't need to move anything around. The way `DisplayNameFor` works is it evaluates the expression to find the property that it retrieve the display name for, and then displays that. You just have to provide it with an expression that will get you there. The only hang up is getting a single instance of `BaseModelChildModel` because the collection itself doesn't have the properties you need to utilize, namely `ChildModel.Name`. With an `IEnumerable`, you can just reference the property directly off the collection, but for anything else, you need an expression for a single instance.

Comment: In other words, if your goal is to get the display name for `ChildModel.Name`, and you're dealing with a `List<BaseModelChildModel>`, you just need an expression like `BaseModelChildModels[0].ChildModel.Name`.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I can totally work with IEnumerable, it will be no problem.

Comment: so… when `IEnumerable<BaseModelChildModel> BaseModelChildModels`, I should be able to do `(Model => Model.BaseModelChildModels.ChildModel.Name)`? VS just complains about `IEnumerable<BaseModelChildModel> does not have a definition for 'ChildModel' and no extension method`. Probably missing something.

Comment: Sorry. I guess I'm thinking about if the actual model for the view is an `IEnumerable`. I guess it doesn't work if it's an `IEnumerable` property on the model. Go back to a list, and just index it, `BaseModelChildModels[0].ChildModel.Name`. Like I said previously, the expression is evaluated only to find the property, so the fact that your list is empty will not cause the `[0]` part to raise an exception.

Comment: and there I was wondering why enumerables behave differently when used as models. I saw this construct around and thought it was neat, but never understood how it works. Thanks for explaining that. Is there a source in which I could read up on these mechanics and how they work?

Comment: Not that I know of honestly. Most of what I've learned has been picked up from various sources. Some things like `DisplayNameFor` being able to work directly with a model of type `IEnumerable<T>` are not really documented at all: just hinted at by tutorials and sample code that uses the convention without explanation.